# I'm trying to move my image on my Canvas with c# and xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm trying to move my PNG across my canvas with C# in a WPF application.

I've tried using extra directives. I've used every keyword I can think of. I've created event handlers and it seems the event isn't firing correctly. And my image fails to move.

```
namespace Pazulu {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Image_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            var alpha = Key.Space;
            if (e.Key == alpha)
                Canvas.SetLeft(pazulu, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

No error message. The expected result should be, at least, to capture an event while debugging, but no event is detected. And my image sits dormant.

Comment: It's unlikely that the Image actually receives the key event. I would add a keydown eventhandler on the window (and verify it fires) and set the image position there (as you already do)

Comment: Copy that.I will put the event on the window to see if it picks it up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to subscribe to the KeyDown event on the Window. Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" KeyDown="MainWindow_OnKeyDown">
    <Canvas>
        <Button Name="MyButton" Canvas.Right="10">Test</Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                //Whatever, just an example
                Canvas.SetRight(MyButton, Canvas.GetRight(MyButton) + 5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```